# ngModel - insert directive in formatter

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an ngModel which one of the attribute contains HTML and some special placeholders, eg:

```
<p>This is test</p>
[image id="1123"]
```

Before I render the value of ngModel I need to replace this special placeholders to HTML, for example:

```
   <div my-directive>
       <img src="/some_image.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

So I would like to have a directive here. I thought that I can use formatter for this. So I added to ngModel.$formatters new function that replaces the string that matches placeholder with directive. My formatter looks like this:

```
function(value){
   var replacedValue = value.replace(regexp, function(match, placeholder){
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.appendChild($compile("<div my-directive></div>")(scope));
      return div.innerHTML;
   })

   return replacedValue;
}
```

The problem is that when my-directive has declared templateURL, the template is not rendered. Only "" is rendered. When I use template in directive, I get the whole HTML for directive rendered, but interpolated values are not replaced, so for example I get:

```
<img ng-src="{{ image.url }}"/>
```

Other problem is that when directive have some event listeners binded to element they are not fired, which I understand, as when the formatter is called this HTML is not in the DOM.

So the question is: how properly implement such feature ? When replace placeholders into directives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong with this approach. I tried too early to compile directives. To make it work, the placeholder replacement can be done in formatter. However compilation should be done in the $render call. In my case $render function looks like this:

```
ngModel.$render = function () {
  element.html(ngModel.$isEmpty(ngModel.$viewValue) ? "" : ngModel.$viewValue);

  if(element.html()) {
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
  }
};
```